# Dynamic buttons in table for delete/edit data with Javascript (CodeIgniter)

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, button

I have created table, which shows users of my web. I want to add "Edit" and "Delete" buttons into table, it was easy (works dynamically), but I how can I set, that each button will work for its table row. For example: each user information row has "Edit" and "Delete" button and these buttons work only for their row (I can edit and delete each user by using their buttons). 
Also, best solution for it will be JavaScript, so any ideas?

Comment: if you dont mind please take a look at [knockout.js](http://knockoutjs.com/examples/gridEditor.html) and you will forget javascript and jquery. Read the documentation

Answer (score 0):

I assume the data for the table comes from a database call, with each user having a record ID.
So either add an id or data attribute to the row when creating the tables rows.

```
<tr data-id="<?php echo $record_id; ?>">
    <td>
        foo
    </td>
    <td>
        bar
    </td>
    <td>
        <a class="edit-link" href="javascript:;" title="Edit User">Edit</a>
    </td>
    <td>
        <a class="delete-link" href="javascript:;" title="Delete User">Delete</a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Using JavaScript you can get the record ID of the user from the data-id of the row.
For edit;

```
$('.edit-link').on('click', function () {
    var user_id = $(this).parent().parent('tr').attr('data-id');
    // now do whatever you want
});
```

For delete;

```
$('.delete-link').on('click', function () {
    var user_id = $(this).parent().parent('tr').attr('data-id');
    // now do whatever you want
});
```

Comment: .live is deprecated :(

Comment: Okey, thanks, but can you explain more deeply:

`var user_id = $(this).parent().parent('tr').attr('data-id');`
I understand, that you create variable "user_id" and set id to it's value, but how it works (what I need to midify and in which place)?

Comment: What bit don't you understand, the getting of the user id or what to do with it?

Comment: I will write, what I understand: "$(this)" - some object, don't know which, ".parent().parent('tr')" - constructors, also don't know which and why you use it, also 'tr' - meaning? "attr('data-id')" - attr - what this function does? "data-id" - probably user's in row id?

Comment: The whole line is just about getting the **data** attribute from the *tr* as the link is in a *td*. `parent()` is just a jquery selector function, the first `parent()` puts you at the *td* that the link is in, the second `parent()` puts you at the *tr*, from where you are getting the *attr* attribute.  
Look at http://api.jquery.com/parent/